# There is no application installed for "shared library" files

Tags: python3, executable

Created a simple python gui window and make executable with PyInstaller. The executable is not able to run firstly on the development machine (of course it will failed when it is copy to a yocto with sato image). The libpython3.8.so.1.0 is in the same folder as the executable.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Just to add:  I am able to run in development machine now with bash. but not at the deploy machine (raspberry pi with Yocto (sato image). with Error "cannot execute binary file:Exec format error ", Dev machine is 64bit  with python 3.8.5 , Deploy machine is Raspi 3B 32bit.. Error because of different architecture ?

Comment: The executable is x86_64 only. Please do `$ file [executable]` ..... An x86_64 executable cannot run with a 32bit **arm** architecture.

Comment: @Knud Larsen: This is what I got : file Hello
Hello: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=24675b0091f38f45c5c1c5484cf24925b439b164, stripped

Comment: First: `pyinstaller` creates executable which will work only with your type CPU and system. It can't run on other CPU or other system like `Windows` or `MacOS`. Second: python wasn't constructed to create `exe` files and programs like `pyinstaller` may have problem to find all needed Python modules, and C/C++ libraries to run it and sometimes you have to manually add missing modules in config file.

Comment: you should rather copy original Python code on Raspberry and install missing Python's modules - you don't need executable for this. if you create code in virtual environment then it is easy to run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to get all needed modules and run it on Raspberry with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. If you see Python's projects on GitHub then you can often see file `requirements.txt`.